# Makefile and wildcard targets

Tags: makefile

I have a directory with many files. I would like to run a command against these files (ie. md5sum). Instead of keep recomputing the checksum I would like to store the checksum. I would like to compute the checksums in a parallel manner (make -j)

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
md5sums: $(addsuffix .md5sum,$(wildcard *.foo))

%.md5sum: %
        md5sum $< > $@
```

That's about the best we can do with the limited description available.

Comment: added a better description

Comment: It looks to have the same amount of information as it did before.  I don't have anything to add to my answer based on those changes.